# BCD decimal score compare in 6502 assembler

Tags: assembly, 6502

hope all is well.

I have a score and high score in my 6502 assembler project.

They are zero page locations :-

```
score           =       $71     ; 71 / 72 / 73 / 74 = 0-99999999
addition        =       $75     ; 75 / 76 / 77 / 78 = 0-99999999
hiscore         =       $79     ; 79 / 7a / 7b / 7c = 0-99999999
hiscore_addition =      $7d     ; 7d / 7e / 7f / 80 = 0-99999999
```

I am using bcd / decimal functions to do addition / subtraction and this all works fine using the addition zero page also mentioned above.

But how, in 6502 would I check if there is a high score - I have tried the following but more often than not the compares fail : -

```
check_if_hi_score:

    sed

    lda     score+0
    cmp     hiscore+0
    bcc     hidone1

    lda     score+1
    cmp     hiscore+1
    bcc     hidone1

    lda     score+2
    cmp     hiscore+2
    bcc     hidone1

    lda     score+3
    cmp     hiscore+3
    bcc     hidone1

    lda     score
    sta     hiscore
    lda     score+1
    sta     hiscore+1
    lda     score+2
    sta     hiscore+2
    lda     score+3
    sta     hiscore+3

hidone1
    cld
    rts
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

M

Comment: What is the byte order? Which bytes are most significant: X+0 or X+3?

Comment: Sorry, X+3 - where x+3 is the left most two digits, and x=0 is the right most two digits

Comment: Let's look at a two byte example. If you want to compare 5000 with 4001, do you want to CMP #$00 with #$01 first, or #$50 with #$40?

Comment: Note that if your target is the NES the `sed` instruction will not work, as its 6502 variant had decimal mode taken out for patent reasons.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to compare multibyte values on 8-bit CPUs is to subtract them without writing the result anywhere.

```
sec
lda hiscore+0
sbc score+0
lda hiscore+1
sbc score+1
lda hiscore+2
sbc score+2
lda hiscore+3
sbc score+3
             ; carry is set if hiscore >= score, carry is reset if score > hiscore
bcs hidone1  ; skip updating the high score
```

Whether the score is decimal or binary, doesn't matter, as the result of comparison will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the decimal mode, I'm not sure whether the compares are working OK in decimal. BCD numbers should compare just OK in binary mode.

upd: also you should start comparing from MSB bytes. If they are equal, proceed to next, otherwise you have the result.

Comment: I was herding him in this direction. You might want to read this on [answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @NickWestgate well I'm not always sure the topic starter is asking about his homework. I've just seen too many times as people with similar experience try to do retroprogramming, incl. game developing.

Comment: Decimal mode does not affect compares in any way.